# Simple midpoint recursion confusion

Tags: java, recursion

I am writing a simple midpoint calculation recursion:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        midPoint(0, array.length - 1, array);
    }
    
    private static void midPoint(int start, int end, int[] array) {
        int mid = (start + end) >>> 1;

        if (start == end) return;
        
        midPoint(start, mid, array);
        midPoint(mid + 1, end, array);      
        
    }
```

This code works fine, but if I change the last 2 lines to this:

```
        midPoint(start, mid - 1, array);
        midPoint(mid, end, array);
```

then code goes into infinite recursion and causes a stack overflow. After printing the values, I realize that in the later, I realize that `midPoint(1, -1, array)` goes into this condition, but conceptually I don't get it i.e. while writing the code how do I realize and avoid this case without having to debug?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually the method will be called with `0` as start and `1` as end.
`mid` will be `0` too as well but the condition `(start == end)` will be false.
the method `midPoint(0, 0-1, array);` will called and the `(start == end)`
won't be true ever and the method will call itself infinity times.
I don't understand what is your code point but maybe you should change it to `(start >= end)`